# React router dom with Typescript using match

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, react-router

I am using React Router Dom version 5 with React v 17 and with TypeScript. I am trying to figure out how to use the `match` object. So far I have:

```
import { BrowserRouter, Route, Switch, match } from 'react-router-dom';


interface DetailsProps {
  match?: match<string> ;
}

const Routing: React.FunctionComponent<DetailsProps> = (props: DetailsProps) => {
   const match = props.match;

   // more routes here
   <Route path={`${match.url}`} render={() => <Component/>} />
}
```

I get there error: Object is possibly 'undefined'.

Any Idea's why? is the type wrong?

Answer (score 0):

You can import it:

```
import { match } from 'react-router-dom';
```

Comment: I have added that, I have updated the question

Answer (score 0):

Your interface says that `match` is an [optional param](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/interfaces.html#optional-properties) and can be `undefined`

```ts
interface DetailsProps {
  match?: match<string> ;
}
```

By removing `?` mark you'll make it required:

```
interface DetailsProps {
  match: match<string> ;
}
```

Comment: Property 'match' is missing in type '{}' but required in type 'DetailsProps'.

Comment: @Sole, you imported it from `'react-router-dom'` and you also trying to reach it through props. You should pick one way from where you want to get `match` isn't it?
So possible you can remove props and just use direct import. But I am not 100% sure what you trying to achieve there.

Comment: The match object is from react-router-dom so you need it from there

Comment: @Sole, so you can try to remove props and interface completely and use it from import.